# In Python, determine if a function calls another function

Tags: python, introspection

How can I determine programmatically if one function calls another function?  I cannot modify either function.

Here's what I want (`source_calls_target`):

```
>>> def check():
>>>     pass
>>> def test_check():
>>>     check()
>>> def source_calls_target(source, target):
>>>     # if source() calls target() somewhere, return True
>>>     ???
>>> source_calls_target(test_check, check)
True
>>> source_calls_target(check, test_check)
False
```

Ideally, I do not want to actually call `target()`.

Ideally, I want to check if a call to `target()` appears within the definition for `source`.  It may or may not actually call it depending on conditional statements.

Comment: How is this relevant to unit testing? Unit testing is about determining behaviour in compliance with a specification.

Comment: @Marcin This checks compliance of test_check with my specification that it must call check().

Comment: @devtk, this is at best code coverage analysis, not unit testing. Unit testing doesn't care if `test_check()` calls `check()` or not. It only deals with the return value and side effects of `test_check()` being conform to the (current) specification.

Comment: Okay, I'll take out the part about unit testing.  I don't care what you call it.  The question still stands.

Comment: Are you able to call the functions during source_calls_target, or are you limited to analysing the source code?

Comment: @Luke Ideally I would like to not actually call the function, but I could live with that if it's the only way.

Comment: Mock (google python mock) can do that. When you mock out the real function, you can use `call_count` to find out. But don't test against the implementation so heavily! Just test the default expected beahvior as thats what unittest is about.

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in knowing whether source _could_ call target? (Are you just asking whether target is present somewhere in the code for source?) Or do you really want to know if it _will_ call target?

Comment: @devtk: this sounds like the wrong way to go about testing your code.  Check that your function behaves as expected, not that it is written a certain way.  And as CppLearner says, mocking can be a good way to isolate one piece of code from another, and test the interface between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can guarantee having access to the source code, you can use `ast.parse`:

```
import ast
call_names = [c.func.id for c in ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(source)))
              if isinstance(c, ast.Call)]
return 'target' in call_names
```

Note that calls are always by name, so it's difficult (and potentially impossible) to tell whether a call is to a particular function or another of the same name.

In the absence of source code, the only way is via disassembly:

```
import dis
def ops(code):
    i, n = 0, len(code)
    while i < n:
        op = ord(code[i])
        i += 1
        if op == dis.EXTENDED_ARG:
            ext = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
            op = ord(code[i + 2])
            i += 3
        else:
            ext = 0
        if op >= dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            arg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256 + ext*65536
            i += 2
            yield op, arg
        else:
            yield op, None

source_ops = list(ops(source.func_code.co_code))
```

The problem is that it's in practice impossible to tell whether a function is *calling* another function or just loading a reference to it; if the other function is passed to `map` or `reduce` etc. then it will be called but passed to another function it might not be.  Practically the sensible thing is to assume that if the function is in `source.func_code.co_names` then it might be called:

```
'target' in source.func_code.co_names
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is the answer I had in mind, just wasn't sure how to implement it.  Will give it a shot.

Comment: This bombs out if the function is indented.  For example, if it's within a class. :/

Comment: @devtk you could use [`textwrap.dedent`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to fix that issue.

Comment: Actually, just `inspect.getsource(source).lstrip()` should do.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example using sys.settrace(). It does require that the source function be called to work. It is also not guaranteed to work, since in some rare instances, two different functions may share the same code object.

```
import sys

def check():
    pass

def test_check():
    check()

def source_calls_target(source, target):
    orig_trace = sys.gettrace()
    try:
        tracer = Tracer(target)
        sys.settrace(tracer.trace)
        source()
        return tracer.called
    finally:
        sys.settrace(orig_trace)

class Tracer:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target
        self.called = False

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if frame.f_code == self.target.func_code:
            self.called = True

print source_calls_target(test_check, check)
print source_calls_target(check, test_check)
```

Comment: Does this only tell you if the target was called at some point, but not directly by source?

Comment: Correct. If you want to know whether the target was called _directly_ by source, then you could also check that frame.f_back.f_code == self.source.func_code (and you would have to pass source to the Tracer instance).

Comment: Very inventive.  Thanks :)  We'll see if anyone can do it without actually calling the target.

Answer (score 1):

Probably very ugly way but it works:

```
import profile

def source_calls_target(source, target):
    pro = profile.Profile()
    pro.run(source.__name__ + '()')
    pro.create_stats()
    return target.__name__ in [ele[2] for ele in pro.stats]
```

Comment: What happens if you have multiple functions with the same name?

Comment: It fails - but as I said, this is ugly solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had been coming up with something that ended up looking very similar to @Luke's good answer. Mine is just a simple function, but it checks if the immediate caller of the target function was the source function:

```
import sys
from functools import partial

def trace_calls(call_list, frame, event, arg):
    if event != 'call':
        return
    call_list.append(frame.f_code)

def test_call(caller, called):
    traces = []
    old = sys.gettrace()
    sys.settrace(partial(trace_calls, traces))
    try:
        caller()
    finally:
        sys.settrace(old)

    try:
        idx = traces.index(called.func_code)
    except ValueError:
        return False

    if idx and traces[idx-1] == caller.func_code:
        return True

    return False
```

And testing...

```
def a():
    b()

def b():
    pass

def c():
    a()


test_call(c,a) #True
test_call(a,b) #True
test_call(c,b) #False
```

Answer (score 1):

This post http://stefaanlippens.net/python_inspect will help you